# How to concatenate values from groups in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

How to concatenate values from groups in a column to make the values of another column

Lets say I have the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Dog','Dog', 'Cat','Cat','Dog'],
                    'Date':   ['01/08/18','01/09/18','01/12/18','02/23/18','01/15/18'],
                    'Meal':   ['DogFood','Bone','Mouse','CatFood','Treat']}
)

  Animal      Date     Meal
0    Dog  01/08/18  DogFood
1    Dog  01/09/18     Bone
2    Cat  01/12/18    Mouse
3    Cat  02/23/18  CatFood
4    Dog  01/15/18    Treat
```

Is it possible to use pandas to groupby Animal, Order by date, then concatenate the values of the Meal column to create a new column that looks like the following

```
  Animal      Date     Meal               Order
0    Cat  01/12/18    Mouse       Mouse CatFood
1    Cat  02/23/18  CatFood       Mouse CatFood
2    Dog  01/08/18  DogFood  DogFood Bone Treat
3    Dog  01/09/18     Bone  DogFood Bone Treat
4    Dog  01/15/18    Treat  DogFood Bone Treat
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df2 = df1.sort_values(['Animal', 'Date'])
df2['Order']=df1.groupby('Animal').Meal.transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
```

Output:

```
  Animal      Date     Meal               Order
2    Cat  01/12/18    Mouse       Mouse CatFood
3    Cat  02/23/18  CatFood       Mouse CatFood
0    Dog  01/08/18  DogFood  DogFood Bone Treat
1    Dog  01/09/18     Bone  DogFood Bone Treat
4    Dog  01/15/18    Treat  DogFood Bone Treat
```

Comment: No need for `lambda`, you can just do `df1.groupby('Animal').Meal.transform(' '.join)` as `str.join` is a function.